# Proper way to structure this SQL query against multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have an issue with a javascript webapp that uses Microsoft Office single sign on. For some reason that I've yet to find out, users are being duplicated in my database. Before I start troubleshooting that, I want to try and clean up the database.

I want to search for any user within the `Employee` table, who doesn't have any suggestions in any of the suggestions tables. Thus, a list of users who haven't made any suggestions, that have duplicate accounts, that I can delete. What would be the best way to go about this?

Also notice how rick (ID 6 & 7) doesn't have any contributions at all. Deleting both accounts would be problematic.

Employee

```
ID    name    hair
--------------------
1     bob     brown
2     jeff    blond
3     jeff    brown
4     steve   none
5     steve   none
6     rick    red
7     rick    red
```

suggestions_lunch

```
ID    suggestion        status
---------------------------------
2     free food         planned
3     warmer coffee     declined
```

suggestions_pay

```
ID    suggestion            status
----------------------------------------------
5     We pay bob too much   investigating
```

Here, ID 4 would be deleted. I guess I will need a second SQL query that shows all users who have multiple accounts with no contributions anywhere.

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee 
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to check for the existence or non existence rather, of a null suggestion value in the 'Suggestions' column would be to check with *is null*

```
    SELECT e.name
          ,sl.suggestion
    FROM Employee e
    JOIN suggestion_lunch sl ON sl.ID = e.ID
    WHERE suggestion IS NULL;
```

This is a good start to what you are trying to do. It will select the name from the *employee* table and the suggestion from the *suggestion_lunch* table.

After the name and suggestion are selected we inner join them on the basis that the suggestion lunch ID is = the employee ID

Finally, we use WHERE to check for null values. Imagine that when we run the query without the WHERE clause... we get back a table with all the employee names and suggestions. To Only display the users with *NO* suggestions we leverage the *IS NULL* clause since the table value will be NULL when no suggestion has been made.

As for the deletion of the duplicates I would suggest a seperate query joined with a GO

Comment: is the second selection  (sl.suggestion) in the select statement ... should this be sl.suggestion_pay  and can you stack it with the others (sl.suggestions_lunch). Then I guess I would need to list them  in the from statement also? From suggestion_lunch sl, suggestions_pay sp  .. somethign like that?

Comment: I have it written that way `SELECT e.name, sl.suggestion` because I am just pulling the column from the table instead of pulling the whole table. I relate this column to the other table later in my JOIN clause so that it will know where I am trying to pull that from. Pulling just the column *sl.suggestions* instead of the table *suggestions_lunch* is more efficient and helps keep results clear. You can pull as many columns from different tables as you would like as long as you JOIN them correctly.